# Edit multiple form responses inside a Google form

Tags: google-drive, google-forms

I am looking an editing form responses on Google Forms.

So basically, I was thinking to create a simple form for the fields I need and having a drop down on the top to edit form responses immediately, without opening a Google spreadsheet.

I searched for current solutions, but couldn't find anything yet.

Is this even possible to edit a form response inside a Google form?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

To be able to edit a response it's required the edit response URL. At this time this link could be got by the respondents right after they submit a response.

An alternative method requires the use of the Google Apps Script that could be used to add a menu to form editor to call a script to  display the response links. For further details see [Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)